# Enum Value Set in Editor Not Changing in Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I am working on a project that requires around 30 buttons in a UI menu. Each of these buttons has a "Loader" script attached to it, and the overall scene has a GameManager object (which persists through scenes).

The GameManager holds an enum with a number of named states equal to the number of buttons.

The idea is I need to populate the next scene with specific content depending on the button pressed, so I thought to assign each of these buttons an enum value, and when clicked the Loader script will change the GameManager's enum to equal the button's value. This way I can avoid making 30+ scenes and instead change the single scene based on the state. When the next scene is loaded, it should determine what the current state is, and does stuff based on that.

The problem is, even though I am able to manually assign the enum value of each individual button in the editor, that doesn't seem to actually do anything. Here are my scripts (abbreviated for only the relevant methods), and sample output when clicking a button.

Here is my GameManager:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

//Used so MenuContent scene knows what random content to populate with    
public enum MenuChosen
{ 
    Tabs, Formal, Casual, Headwear, Accessories, Speakers, ComputerParts, 
    GameConsoles, MobilePhones, Furniture, Lighting, OfficeSupplies, Gadgets, Toys, 
    Summer, SchoolSupplies, ArtsCrafts, Checking, Savings, PayPal, OtherAccount, Visa, 
    MasterCard, AirMiles, OtherCards, Food, Retail, Digital, OtherCoupons, 
    PayTransaction, ScheduledPayments, LoanPayment, MobileRecharge
};

public MenuChosen chosen;
}
```

And here is my Loader class. It is attached to every button. In the editor, I selected four buttons, and manually changed their states to "Formal", "Casual", "Headwear", and "Accessories", via the drop-down list in the inspector for each of them.

The Loader class creates a reference to the GameManager object, and attempts to change its "chosen" enum variable to be equal to the value that was set in the inspector window (which is called "MenuOption" in the loader).

```
public class Loader : MonoBehaviour {

public GameManager gm;

public GameManager.MenuChosen MenuOption;

private void Start()
{
    gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();

    Debug.Log("Current Loader State: " + MenuOption);
}

public void LoadMenuContent()
{
    Debug.Log("Button's State is: " + MenuOption);
    gm.chosen = MenuOption;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MenuContent");
    Debug.Log("Current state is: " + gm.chosen);
}
}
```

When I first run the game, the debug messages show that the buttons' enum values are indeed changed:

```
Current Loader State: Accessories
Current Loader State: Headwear
Current Loader State: Formal
Current Loader State: Casual
```

However, the logs printed in the LoadMenuContent() method show something different:

```
Button's State is: Tabs
Current state is: Tabs
```

So even though it shows that the buttons' MenuOption is properly changed, once it reaches LoadMenuContent(), which is called when the button is pressed, then somehow the state has changed back to the default state, "Tabs".

Any thoughts on why the enum might be changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what my issue was.

Due to the large quantity of buttons, I had resorted to copying and pasting them.

This meant that each button was identical, and had its own copy of the Loader script as a component. By doing this, I was able to change the individual values of the enum of each individual button in the inspector.

***However,*** this also meant that each and every button, in the OnClick() method, were all still holding a reference to the *original* button that I had copied and pasted. So these buttons were independent, but they all referenced the same exact script from the same exact button, who's state had never been changed from the default.

In order to fix this, I had to go in and manually drag each button into its own OnClick() method as a reference to itself, so they were properly calling the correct function from their *own* individual Loader script.